How to customize HTML report file name in Playwright
I'm trying to customize the Playwright's HTML report file name.
I've tried both fileName and outputFile settings but no luck.
I have to mention that when I set outputFolder it changes the folder accordingly.
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  reporter: [
    [
      "html",
      {
        fileName: "test-results.html", // Not working
        outputFile: "myFile.html", // Not working
        outputFolder: "myFolder", // Working
      },
    ],
});

In other reporters such as json or junit these settings works just fine:
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  reporter: [
    ['json', {  outputFile: 'test-results.json' }] // Working
  ],
});

I couldn't find anything useful in Playwright Reporters Docs regarding this problem.
